# suppose I select the first select option it should show me the list of the second select option. How can I do it in angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-select

suppose I select the first select1 option1 it should automatically show me the list of the options in select 2 and when I select option 2 in select1  it should show me a list of options in select2. How can I do it in angular2?

[image: support image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c8wsuc?file=src/app/app.component.ts
If this solution doesn't fit you please put some example code and show where you have a problem.

Comment: after selecting the options and when I click the submit button it should go to the url as per the selected option..How can I do it?